# Problema al imprimir dinamicamente con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, bucle-for

Tengo la siguiente function la cual contiene un Ajax que trae los datos de usuarios e informes correspondientes similar a esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y hasta alli me funciona perfectamente con la function que esta a continuación

```
function buscador(){
 var string = $("#buscar_nombre").val();
 var inicio = $("#ingresar_inicio").val();
 var fin = $("#ingresar_fin").val();

 $('#error_conexion').hide();
 $('#sin_resultados').hide();
 $('#cargando_buscar').show();
$.ajax({
        url: "post/asistencia_ver_jugador.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {
        'string': string,
        'inicio': inicio,
        'fin': fin
    },success: function(respuesta){
        alert(JSON.stringify(respuesta));

        if(respuesta== ""){ //jugador sin informes
            $("#tabla_ver_informes tbody").empty();

            var markup = '<tr class="sin_fondo"><td></td><td style="height:80px; width:10px;"></td><td></td><td><center><h5 style="color:#555555;"><i class="icon-file-alt"></i> Sin jugadores</h5></center></td></tr>';

            $("#tabla_ver_informes tbody").append(markup);
            $("#graficos_informes_resumen").hide();
            $('#cargando_buscar').hide();
            $('#sin_resultados').show();
            $('#boton_editar').hide();
            $('.boton_refresh').hide();
        }else{

            // INICIO IMPRESION NUMEROS
            var opend = $("#ingresar_fin").val();
            var open = new Date(opend);
            open.setDate(open.getDate() + 1);

            var xtotal = 0;
            for (var z = 0; z < respuesta.length; z++) {
                if (respuesta[z]['informe'].length > xtotal)
                {xtotal = respuesta[z]['informe'].length; } 
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {$("#numero_"+i).empty(); }

            for (var i = xtotal-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                var day = open.getDate();
                $("#numero_"+i).html(day);
                open.setDate(open.getDate() - 1);
            }
            // FIN IMPRESION NUMEROS

            $('#boton_editar').prop("disabled",false);
            window.jugadores_scouting = respuesta; 
            $("#tabla_ver_informes tbody").empty();
            var count = 1;

            for(var i=0; i < respuesta.length; i++){ 

                if (respuesta[i]['informe'] == '') {
                    // alert("vacio");
                    var asistencia = 0;
                    var inasistencia = 0;
                    var justificada = 0;
                    var injustificada = 0;
                    var valores = [];

                    var asistenciaP = 0;
                    var injustificadaP = 0;
                    var justificadaP = 0;
                    var porcentajeTotal = 1;

                    var vall= '';

                    vall = '<td><center><div style="background-color:white ;border-radius: 50%;width: 10px;height: 10px"></div></center></td>';
                    valores.push(vall);


                }else{
                    alert("SI TIENE");

                    var porcentajeTotal = respuesta[i]['informe'].length;
                    var asistencia = 0;
                    var inasistencia = 0;
                    var justificada = 0;
                    var injustificada = 0;
                    var valores = [];
                    var color = "white";
                    var asistenciaP = 0;
                    var injustificadaP = 0;
                    var justificadaP = 0;

                    for (var j = respuesta[i]['informe'].length-1; j >=0; j--) {

                        if (respuesta[i]['informe'][j]['asistencia'] == '') {
                            color = "white";
                            asistencia = asistencia + 0;
                        }

                        else if (respuesta[i]['informe'][j]['asistencia'] == 1) {
                            color = "#5cb85c";
                            asistencia = asistencia + 1;

                        }else{
                            inasistencia = inasistencia + 1;

                            if (respuesta[i]['informe'][j]['justificacion'] == 1) {
                            color = "orange"; 
                            justificada = justificada + 1;

                            }else{
                            color = "red";
                            injustificada = injustificada + 1;
                            }

                        }

                    var vall= '';
                    vall = '<td><center><div style="background-color:'+color+' ;border-radius: 50%;width: 10px;height: 10px"></div></center></td>';
                    valores.push(vall);

                    }//FOR

                    injustificada = inasistencia - justificada;

                }


                var asistenciaP = parseInt(asistencia) / porcentajeTotal;
                    asistenciaP = asistenciaP.toFixed(2);
                    asistenciaP = asistenciaP * 100;
                    asistenciaP = parseInt(asistenciaP);

                var injustificadaP = parseInt(injustificada) / porcentajeTotal;
                    injustificadaP = injustificadaP.toFixed(2);
                    injustificadaP = injustificadaP * 100;
                    injustificadaP = parseInt(injustificadaP);

                var justificadaP = parseInt(justificada) / porcentajeTotal;
                    justificadaP = justificadaP.toFixed(2);
                    justificadaP = justificadaP * 100;
                    justificadaP = parseInt(justificadaP);


                var markup = '<tr onClick="accesoDetalle('+i+')" style="cursor:pointer; color:#555555; font-size:13px;"><td style="width:130px;margin-left:10px"><img src="img/logito.png"> '+respuesta[i]['nombre']+' '+respuesta[i]['apellido']+'</td><td style="width:100px;max-width:100px"><div style="display:-webkit-inline-box;padding-top:4px;padding-bottom:4px"><div style=";height:16px;width:90px;height:20px;border: solid 1px red;border-radius:5px"><div style="border-radius:4px;height:16px;background-color: red;width: '+injustificadaP+'%;height:21px"></div></div><b style="margin-left:2px;color:red;display:inline">'+injustificada+'</b></div></td><td style="width:100px;max-width:100px"><div style="display:-webkit-inline-box;padding-top:4px;padding-bottom:4px"><div style=";height:16px;width:90px;height:20px;border: solid 1px orange;border-radius:5px"><div style="border-radius:4px;height:16px;background-color: orange;width: '+justificadaP+'%;height:21px"></div></div><b style="margin-left:2px;color:orange;display:inline">'+justificada+'</b></div></td><td style="width:100px;max-width:100px"><div style="display:-webkit-inline-box;padding-top:4px;padding-bottom:4px"><div style=";height:16px;width:90px;height:20px;border: solid 1px #5cb85c;border-radius:5px"><div style="border-radius:4px;height:16px;background-color: #5cb85c;width: '+asistenciaP+'%;height:21px"></div></div><b style="margin-left:2px;color:#5cb85c;display:inline">'+asistencia+'</b></div></td>'+valores+'</tr>';

                $("#tabla_ver_informes tbody").append(markup);


            }


            $('#boton_editar').show();
            $('.boton_refresh').hide();
        } 
        $('#cargando_buscar').hide();
        $('#error_conexion').hide();
        $('#sin_resultados').hide();

    },error: function(){// will fire when timeout is reached
        $('#cargando_buscar').hide();
        $('#sin_resultados').hide();
        $('#error_conexion').show();
        $('#boton_editar').hide();
        $('.boton_refresh').show();
    }, timeout: 15000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
}
```

Pero el detalle es que como se muestra en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de poner una fecha en la que no existan registros del jugador 2 no me lo imprime en pantalla, en otras palabras, luego de que extendí el rango de "fecha inicio" de 2019-06-10 a 2019-06-09 osea un día menos, entonces ya no me muestra nada del jugador.

Lo que deseo es que cuando no haya un resultado en ese informe entonces me imprima un circulo blanco o lo salte y deje el espacio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disculpen pero ya resolvi mi pregunta, lo que debia hacer era hacer un condicional dentro de este for

```
for (var j = respuesta[i]['informe'].length-1; j >=0; j--) {
```

en el cual preguntara si

```
respuesta[i]['informe'][j]== null
```

y esa era el problema, que en el caso de ser null no habia una respuesta y el for se quedaba alli.

Comment: excelente, ahora marca la respuesta como aceptada :D

Comment: Existe un problema, y es que no puedo marcarla como aceptada sino hasta dentro de 2 dias, pero si quieres copia y pega y coloca tu una respuesta y yo marco aceptada la tuya... Cortesia de la casa.

Comment: Agradezco la oferta, tengo que rechazarla pues ha sido tu esfuerzo, no el mío y en el sitio hay reglas :) Espera y márcala como aceptada, ayudarás a mantener el orden en el sitio :D Saludos

Comment: Listo :D gracias por ver la pregunta igualmente.